# How do I use intellij platform ui components in plugin with the ui designer?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating an IntelliJ plugin and use IntelliJ's UI designer for my popups, but I would like to use some components from the IntelliJ platform, some of which are created with the UI designer, but I can't add them to the palette because the `.form` files are not included in the dependency. Is there some other dependency I can add that includes those `.form` files or some other solution to this?

I tried importing the components into the palette and it works for some because they extend classes like JPanel, but others that are UI designer forms don't because it can't determine them as such because it is looking for the not included `.form` file.

Comment: Please contact JetBrains development team directly as described at https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html to address this query